# Values either not being stored or not displaying correctly

Tags: c

I am trying to get this program to display the amount of pieces entered for each name entered as well as calculate the price. At the moment the program only shows the last entered name and 0 for pieces and 0.00 for price, regardless of what I enter for pieces. (I'm not at all sure about the final for loop I had so it is greyed out.)

I am mostly looking for a nudge in the right direction, I am very new to this and am prone to overthinking things and making it harder for myself.  Here is the code and I appreciate any tips.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20
int main()
{
   int total=0,comp, ctr=0;
   char name[SIZE];
   float price;

   printf("Please enter the number of pieces: ");
   scanf("%d", &comp);

   while( comp != 0)
   {
       // ctr = ctr + 1;
       printf("Please enter the name: ");
       scanf("%19s", name);
       printf("Please enter the number of pieces: ");
       scanf("%d", &comp);

       if ( comp > 0 && comp < 200)
       {
           price = comp * .50;
       }

       if ( comp > 199 && comp < 400)
       {
           price = comp * .55;
       }

       if ( comp > 400 && comp < 600)
       {
           price =  comp * .60;
       }

       if ( comp > 600)
       {
           price = comp * .65;
       }

       ctr = ctr + 1;
   }

   printf("%s%13s%13s\n","Name", "Pieces", "Price");
   //for ( name[7] =0; name[7] <= 7; ++name[7]);
   // {
       printf("%s%12d%12.2f\n", name, comp, price);
   // }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Go a few steps back and simplify what your are doing. I recommend to first make a program which asks for 5 prices, stores them and outputs them. Then do something slightly more complex, by asking for the number of prices to work with first. Then add a name to each price. The idea is described here https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: Having asked how many pieces, you should then make a `for` loop.

Comment: ... since you seem to use `int comp` for two different reasons.

Comment: What happens when `comp == 400` or `comp == 600`? There are some gaps in the logic. You could deal with this by using `else` clauses testing **one** increasing value - you are testing the same value twice, but got it wrong because of those gaps.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to do with this logic, but based on what I see in the code, here's why you are seeing the output you are seeing:

1. It looks like you are trying to store a list of named items. If so, you would need a 2-dimension character array. In C, strings are nothing but an array of characters, so your name[] array can only store a single string, which is why each iteration of your while() loop overwrites the name[] string. So if you want to build a list of names, you'll need something like: name[NAME_SIZE][NUM_OF_NAMES].
2. Your comp and price variables always print as 0 because, as the code is written, comp==0 is the exit condition of the loop. In order to store the successive values of comp and price, you'd need to make those two arrays of int and float respectively.

Try the following code. It may not do exactly what you are looking for, but I think it will get you one step closer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NSTRINGS 10   // Max number of named items
#define MAXSTRING 20  // Max name string length

int main()
{
    int total=0, comp[NSTRINGS];
    char name[NSTRINGS][MAXSTRING];
    float price[NSTRINGS];

    for(int i = 0; i < NSTRINGS; i++) {
        printf("Please enter the number of pieces: ");
        scanf("%d", &comp[i]);
        if(comp[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }

        printf("Please enter the name: ");
        scanf("%19s", name[i]);

        if ( comp[i] > 0 && comp[i] < 200)
        {
            price[i] = comp[i] * .50;
        }

        if ( comp[i] > 199 && comp[i] < 400)
        {
            price[i] = comp[i] * .55;
        }

        if ( comp[i] > 400 && comp[i] < 600)
        {
            price[i] =  comp[i] * .60;
        }

        if ( comp[i] > 600)
        {
            price[i] = comp[i] * .65;
        }
    }

    printf("%s%13s%13s\n","Name", "Pieces", "Price");
    for(int i = 0; i < NSTRINGS && comp[i] !=0; i++) {
        printf("%s%12d%12.2f\n", name[i], comp[i], price[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output then looks something like this:

```
$ ./a.out 
Please enter the number of pieces: 20
Please enter the name: Test1
Please enter the number of pieces: 456
Please enter the name: Test2
Please enter the number of pieces: 698
Please enter the name: Test3
Please enter the number of pieces: 0
Name       Pieces        Price
Test1          20       10.00
Test2         456      273.60
Test3         698      453.70
$
```

Hope this helps.